# Can I get the raw querystring in a django middleware?

Tags: django

Specifically my middleware is interested to differentiate between a GET request on:

1. /admin/app/model/?
2. /admin/app/model/

URL #1 was initiated with a dangling question mark. 
From my experiments, django's HttpRequest swallows it up and I am unable to differentiate between the two. Is there a way to obtain the raw nonfiltered query string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?` should be escaped as `%3F`. So, may be you should choose another symbol, without such problems?

Comment: This problem stems from the links created for ModelAdmin, when you declare a date_hierarchy. It creates a "All Dates" link to reset selection and django generates a dangling question mark.

Comment: @BonAmi `url/?` and `url/` are exactly the same and will (and should) be treated in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be possible.  Typically a django application is served from behind the WSGI interface, by the time the request gets to django it's already been parsed into PATH_INFO (before the?) and QUERY_STRING (after the ?).  When django runs get_full_path it's just concatenating those two things with a ? in the middle if needed.

It's also a bad idea: HTTP does not expect URLs to behave differently with a trailing ?, as that just means an empty set of parameters, which is the same thing that the absence of a ? means.  As well as being confusing, this may cause interoperability problems, as a proxy or web browser might drop the trailing '?' in the expectation that it should have no effect.